# @Given Glue not executed from Stepdef in cucumber but @Before setup() method is executed

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

In cucumber maven project.
Feature file :

```
        Feature: Smoke Test for Home
 
Scenario: positive scenario
    Given Open "JTMS_PORTAL"
    #When application open successfully
    #Then validate title as "Welcome: Mercury Tours"
    #And Close Application
```

StepDef File :

```
package jtms.stepdef;

import cucumber.api.java.Before;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;

public class LoginStepDef {
    
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        System.out.println("In login stepdef");
}
    @Given("^Open \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void open(String arg1) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("In login stepdef2 with Given annotation");
    }
}
```

TestRunner :

```
package jtms.testrunner;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "features/jtms/home.feature",
glue="jtms.stepdef",
dryRun=false
        )

public class TestRunner {
}
```

Cosole output:

```
In login stepdef
```

Project structure:
[image]
Issue:
@Given from stepdef not print the print statement, but @Before is executed and print the output 'In login stepdef'. please help, thank you in advance.

Comment: do you see an error?

Answer (score 0):

can you change the value of the feature in cucumber options to below

```
features = {"classpath:features"}
```